# Updating information on the map in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dynamic-text

I usually do a lot of maps with ArcGIS but I need to dynamize the information about the number of map, name of map, date of map.

How can I do automatically?

I have a template of map with a box in which I need this information.

Comment: You would probably look for dynamic texts which you can insert into page layout: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/what-is-dynamic-text-.htm

Comment: Some more details would be quite useful, could you also tell us what version of arc you using? Have you played with Data Driven Pages yet?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reviewing the documentation on [What is dynamic text?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/what-is-dynamic-text-.htm)

> Dynamic text is text placed on a map layout that changes based on the
>   current properties of the map document, data frame, and Data Driven
>   Page. Create dynamic text for such things as the following:
>
> - A user name
> - The date a map document was saved
> - The file path for the map document
> - The page numbers and names that update automatically for each page in a series of Data Driven Pages